# create dynamic variable names to retrieve data from Firestore in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

[This is the screenshot of my firestore dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kuqt.png)

I would like to create a for loop to access each of the latitudeVariation data and add it to an html table. 
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
for(i=0;i<data.counter;i++){
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML =data.window['latitudeVariation'+i];`
```

My data object looks like this:

```
counter: 13
latitude: 12.1070837
latitudeVariation0: 12.1070837
latitudeVariation1: 12.1070837
latitudeVariation2: 12.1063489
```

Comment: Can you post the sample response, you loop through the object using keys. I can add detailed code if you can post the response please.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? What does `data` look like?

Comment: `track.js:44 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitudeVariation0' of undefined` this is the response iam getting from console @ZainZafar

Comment: It means that window object that you are trying to access isn't defined. Try logging using this statement `console.log(data.window)`

Comment: Actually I don't have a window object inside data. I just want to append the variable i to the end of latitudeVariation and access data like `latitudeVariation+i` @ZainZafar

Comment: I have posted the answer let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to traverse through the object using keys that are defined

```js
var data = {
  counter: 3,
  latitude: 12.1070837,
  latitudeVariation0: 12.1070837,
  latitudeVariation1: 12.1070837,
  latitudeVariation2: 12.1063489,
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.counter; i++) {
  var key = 'latitudeVariation'+i;
  if (data[key]) {
    console.log(data[key]);
  }
}
```